# Automatic update of date and time in python

Tags: python, qt, date, pyqt, pyqt4

1. List item

I am trying to display on my windows current date and time.date and time is not updating automatically.when I am closing and running my python file its fetching the system date and time.please find my code on below

```
import datetime
import threading


now = datetime.datetime.now()
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 110, 241, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.start(10 * 1000) # 10 seconds

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form",QtCore.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well, you'd need a timer to update the time every second I'd say!? You can use a `QTimer` or just the timer of every `QObject` if you want.

Comment: you are asking me to use threading.Timer..I am correct or not

Comment: usually a timer is implemented using a background thread yes, but you don't need to worry about that if you just use a `QTimer` for example. Just take a look at the official clock example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html

Comment: self.timer = QTimer()                                                                       self.timer.start(10*1000)                                                                                 I have add this timer on  my UI_form.but its not working

Comment: yes you need to connect a slot to the `timeout` signal of the timer, that will be called every 10 seconds or whatever you set it to. in that slot you can just update your clock value or whatever you want to do every 10 seconds.

Comment: self.label.setText(_translate("Form",QtCore.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), None)) but its not working

Comment: can you update the question with the code how you actually used the timer?

Comment: self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
 self.timer.start(10 * 1000) # 10 seconds

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form",QtCore.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), None))

Comment: Please update your question you can't write multi line code in comments. But from what I can see you never connect the timeout signal of the timer so it does nothing. I'm no python pro but I guess you need to do something like `self.timer.timeout.connect(self.yourtimeoutslot)`

Comment: @user1811790 try with my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a timer that runs from time to time, and call the `retranslateUi` function.

```
timer = QtCore.QTimer(Form)
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: ui.retranslateUi(Form))
timer.start(1000)
```

We must update the time in retranslateUi for it we modify it to:

```
def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Form",now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), None))
```

**complete code:**

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 110, 241, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form",now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), None))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    timer = QtCore.QTimer(Form)
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: ui.retranslateUi(Form))
    timer.start(1000)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```